# FatalThrowableError in web.php line 86: Class 'app\Post' not found in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.4

i tried ran my page (http://homestead.app/read) with laravel but print this "FatalThrowableError in web.php line 86:
Class 'app\Post' not found" error message.

I use laravel 5.4

My app/Post.php

```
<?php
namespace routes; 

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes; 

class Post extends Model 
{ 

use SoftDeletes; 


protected $dates = ['deleted_at']; 

protected $filleable = [ 
    'title',         
    'content' 

]; 

    public function user(){ 

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    } 


}
```

My app/Http/Controller/postController.php

```
<?php

namespace route\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Post;

class PostsController extends Controller
{...}
```

and my app/Post.php

```
<?php

use app\Post;

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/read', function(){

    $posts = Post::all();

    foreach($posts as $post) {
            return $post->title;
    }

  });
```

Comment: Try `App\Post` instead of lowercase `app`.... (check your model to confirm how it is defined)

Comment: I suggest, changing your namespace in your app/Post.php to
`namespace App;`